# Spring populating form fields based on value from select box

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I have select box where I select name of employee from list of all employees. What I want to achieve is to get other attributes of object employee. I use javascript to achieve it but I always get the first element from the list (index 0). Here is the code:

```
<sf:select path="employee" onchange="change()" >
     <sf:option value="">
        Choose employee
     </sf:option>
     <sf:options itemLabel="employeeName" items="${employeeList}"
            itemValue="employeeId" />
    </sf:select>

<input id="licenseNr"/>
```

And javascript:

```
 <script>
    function change(){
         var comboIndex = document.getElementById("employee").value;        
         document.getElementById("licenseNr").value=("${employeeList.get(comboIndex).licenseNr}"); 
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem by adding parameter in url with jquery

```
$(function() {
        $("#employee")
                .change(
                        function(e) {
                            var option = $(this).val();                             
                            var newUrl = "someUrl?id="+option;
                            window.location=newUrl;                             
                        });
    });
```

In controller I have added RequestParam annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue="-1")
 Integer id,Model model){
if(id>0){   
    Employee employee = service.fetchEmployeeById(id);      
                model.addAttribute("employee", employee);}
    return "someUrl";}
```

Then I have added value to text field

```
<input id="licenseNr" value="${employee.licenseNr}" />
```